Is this dialogue Got or get?
A Primary School Story “Ranger Anne and the Clever Tiger”
Inside it says:
She thinks, “Tim, it’s time you got some exercises.”
Why is it got and not get?

We say "in" the story and use "inside" with buildings.

Does this answer your question? It's time I go to bed vs It's time I went to bed?

@TimR: That's true, though we might say "inside the book"...

@psmears Yes, but "inside the book" refers to the book as a physical object.  Inside the book there is a pop-up cardboard pyramid.  We wouldn't say "inside the book Tom and Huck get into trouble".

@TimR: No, indeed we wouldn't, but we might say "inside it says XXX", like in the question. It's more likely to be used in an example like "On the cover it says XXX, but inside it says YYY", but I don't think how it's used in the question is definitely wrong...

@psmears When speaking of a story, one uses "in".  The story is not the book and the book is not the story.  If you were reading a math textbook, and then wanted to refer to a formula given in a particular chapter, you wouldn't say "inside chapter 6" merely because the chapter happens to be inside the book you're holding in your hands.

@TimR: No, but this isn't a maths textbook, so I'm not clear what point you're making? They're clearly talking about a story that is in a book...

@psmears With the math textbook and the chapter,, I was drawing a distinction between the physical book on the one hand and on the other, what is presented in the text (in the non-physical sense of that word).  We use inside with the physical thing and in with the  text.  To talk about what a character does or says inside a book is not idiomatic.

@TimR. I don't disagree with what you say - but in the question, it doesn't say "Inside, a character says [character's words]" - it says "Inside [the book], it says [quote from book]" - i.e. an impersonal, rather than referring to a character. That's perfectly idiomatic. (And, to be clear to OP, changing "inside" to "in" in the question, without making any other changes, would definitely make it unidiomatic!)

@Psmears OP is quoting from the story. The story, unlike the physical book, doesn't have an "inside" and an "outside".  Agreed, OP would have to rephrase the question  to something like In the story so-and-so says  "....."

@Timr: Yes, quoting from the story... which is located... inside the book! Just like all of the "inside the book" examples in the search I linked above. You're right that it would be different if the quote were "*Inside, Tim says to Anne ...", though.

@psmears  The story is not "located inside the book". That is "where" we disagree.  The story has a virtual existence, not a physical one. One typeset representation of the words of the story is found inside the book.   I don't mean to be counting angels on pinheads, just pointing out what is considered idiomatic when talking about a story.  We say "In the story..." not "Inside the story ..." and when we want to refer to the story as story we don't refer to the physical book.

We use the past tense in constructions with it's time.

We can use the expression it's (high) time + subject + past verb form to say it is time to do something now that should have been done a long time ago.


It's high time we went to bed.


It's time we took responsibility for our planet.


English is a strange language.

For what it's worth, although the references I consulted agree that only the past tense or to-infinitive are grammatical with "it's time," the present tense ("it's time you get...") also sounds perfectly natural to my and my family's (midwest Am.E.) ears. I suspect people may encounter this form even if it's proscribed.

@TypeIA  Both forms are grammatical and have their own nuance.  It's time we get you some new sneakers. It's time we got you some new sneakers.

When we say "It is time you {did something}" or "It  is time we {did something}", we are making an exhortation, and such  urging statements can be  marked with a back-shift of tense (to past tense) to distinguish them from declarations of fact.
Compare:

It's time we go. (a simple statement of fact)


It's time we went.   (There is some urgency involved, even if it is only very slight. We should go.)

P.S. A parent could say to a child

It's time we take you to the doctor.

and that non-backshifted version could fit a situation where the intended meaning was "you're going to the doctor -- it's not open to discussion";
or the parent could say :

It's time we took you to the doctor.

and that utterance could fit a situation where  the intended nuance was "We really must take you to the doctor. We've held off more than long enough to see that you're not getting any better."

I have never heard "It's time we go" used in Australia. "It's time to go" is common, or "it is time we went".

@Peter I suspect that "it's time we go" is not very common in any variety of English. It's just a hypothetical sentence used to illustrate the difference.

I've heard it just like that, but it's regional. Most often it would be something like "It's time we go to bed" or "It's time we go to work"  or 'It's time we go to the police".  You can use to the non-backshifted version to stress the reasonableness of the declaration, to present it as something that needs no debate.
